# Regular expression to validate sum of numerics

Tags: regex

I want to validate the user input,

it should accept,

```
1+2
1.2+56+3.5
```

it should not accept any alphabets, special characters other than . and +

and mainly it should not accept ++ and ..

please help me with regular expression.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Perhaps you could parse the expression by attempting to `eval`uate  it

Comment: This is what i have http://jsfiddle.net/DwKZh/763/ , I tried all expression provided here but still allowing me to enter invalid inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
var regex = /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(\+[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)*$/;
"1+2".match(regex); // not null
"1.2+56+3.5".match(regex); // not null
"1++2".match(regex); // null
"1..2".match(regex); // null
```

online: http://regex101.com/r/zJ6tP7/1

Comment: This is what i have http://jsfiddle.net/DwKZh/763/  , I tried all expression provided here but still allowing me to enter invalid inputs.

Comment: please give an example of an invalid input that the satisfies the regex

Comment: none of those strings match the regex - try them out on the regex101 page I linked to or just in the JS console in your browser: "1++2".match(REGEX HERE)

Comment: added more example above, also please distribute some upvotes and accept an answer so that people will be more likely to help you in the future

Answer (score 0):

Something like this *should* suffice

```
^([+]?\d+(\.\d+)?)*$
```

http://regex101.com/r/qE2kW1/2

Source: [Validate mathematical expressions using regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009320/validate-mathematical-expressions-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Note that I'm assuming it should not accept .+ or +. as well. I'm not assuming that you require checking for multiple decimals prior to an addition, meaning this will accept 3.4.5 I'm also assuming you want it to start and end with numbers, so .5 and 4+ will fail.

```
(\d*[\.\+])*(\d)*
```

This takes any amount of number values, followed by a . or a +, any number of times, followed by any other number value.

To avoid things like 3.4.5 you'll likely need to use some sort of lookaround.

EDIT: Forgot to format regular expression.